# F1 and Exact-Match (EM) Score in Extractive QA NLP

Tags: nlp, bert, huggingface, llm, question-answering

I have a question as to how the F1 should be calculated in NLP and whether the text normalization is optional or not.

So I have been working on a project where we created a closed-domain extractive QA dataset from scratch, and we are trying to finetune and assess the performance of several LLMs in this new dataset. I came across different definitions of the F1 score, sometimes with text normalization ([like in here](https://qa.fastforwardlabs.com/no%20answer/null%20threshold/bert/distilbert/exact%20match/f1/robust%20predictions/2020/06/09/Evaluating_BERT_on_SQuAD.html#Exact-Match)) and sometimes not. I have run all my experiments without the normalization step for both the EM and F1 scores. Should I rerun all experiments?

Is the